# Cannot access nginx site from external IP

Tags: networking, server, nginx, port-forwarding

So I'm having a quite strange problem.

I've just bought an HPE ProLiant Gen8 microserver to run Plex and webserver.

So first off I installed Plex and port forwarded 32400 on my Asus RT-AC66U router. Works like a charm, I can access from my cellular connection through x.x.x.x:32400.

Next was the webserver. I installed nginx, php, mysql and could access the test site from within the network. Then I tried to portforward port 80 on my router, but no luck. In the Asus interface it informs me that port 80 could be an issue

> When your network's firewall is disabled and you set 80 as the HTTP
>   server's port range for your WAN setup, then your http server/web
>   server would be in conflict with RT-AC66U's web user interface.

So first I tried changing the portforward to external port 8080 and local port 80. No luck

Then changed the site port to 8080 and the portforward to external port 8080 and nothing in local port. No luck.

Perhaps nginx wasn't listening to requests from external IP addresses

```
sudo netstat -tanpl|grep nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      56292/nginx -g daem
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      56292/nginx -g daem
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      56292/nginx -g daem
```

In case there was a firewall I disabled it

```
udo ufw disable
```

My nginx default site config is

```
server {
        listen 8080 default_server;
        listen [::]:8080 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Comment: did you fix this ?